# Add a comment to a bounty

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, bounties

Now that you can put a bounty on someone else question. It would be nice to be able to attach a comment to the bounty, to explain what you expect opening it. For me an important motivation of offering a bounty is that I would like some overlooked aspect of a question to be explored. It's easy to explain it in the question for your own questions, but on someone else question I feel it would be better to explain what you expect offering more exposure to a question.

Comment: I like this idea

Answer (score 9):

This is now completed, you can add a custom bounty message at the end of the start bounty process:

[image: custom message]

see also: [How should bounties be categorized?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103956/how-should-bounties-be-categorized/103981#103981)

Comment: Is there minimum length for the custom message, or some word filter?

Comment: @waffles The problem is that while it allows markup, even 2500 characters, it strips carriage returns; so when you nicely format your comment and put a blank line between paragraphs it turns it into a wall of text.

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of obvious, but you could simply add a comment to the question.

Comment: When there is a lot of comments for a question, it's hard to spot someone comment.

Comment: **USE ALL UPPERCASE AND BOLD.** There's nothing wrong with that, right :P

Comment: You still need to click "add / show XXX more comments" in order to see that **UPPERCASE BOLD** text.

Comment: @Holy - good point. You'll also need sockpuppet accounts to upvote your own comments.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with this feature. The purpose of the bounty is explained in the faq.
Imagine that you have to **explain** why you asked a question or why you answered to a question.
If the one who gives the bounty choose to explain why, he can do it in the comments; no problem. But don't make that mandatory.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants this to be mandatory; it could just be an optional feature that would be extremely useful to a large minority of users.  Though I agree that if it was mandatory, this would be not very useful.

Comment: @templatetypedef As far as I like communication here, the bounty is a sensitive issue. Imagine somebody saying "I give the bounty because I want X", and somebody complies to that, even when X strays away from the original question.