# "Spare" rep for use on bounties for points over the cap

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties

There are lots of very good reasons for the 200 point cap, but at the same time it adds an anticlimactic area above the 200 point cap each day.

Why not let the points over the 200 cap go into another counter that can only be used for bounties?  It would encourage the use of bounties on some older questions which don't get much love, but which would be useful to have good answers to.  All while keeping to the intention of the cap in the first place.

(This suggestion is from Vitaly Mijiritsky, but he's too lazy to post it :P)

Comment: This *probably* opens some nasty exploitable loopholes, but then again you'd have to earn 200+ rep to be *able* to exploit this ...

Comment: Maybe limited it to people that have over 10K rep

Comment: @IanRingrose Good idea. In that case it can be defined as a new privilege.

Comment: @IanRingrose: I would like that idea if I didn't only have 3k rep :(  The principle of adding it as a privilege is good though.

Comment: hmm http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106765/free-bounties-good-or-bad-idea giving high rep users special bounty rights is not necessarily a good thing, this essentially gives all our top users unlimited bounties

Comment: Nobody said unlimited.  Even if it is a 1/10 ratio of points, at least it still gives an incentive to be helpful beyond 200 points / day.

Comment: @john but that incentive already exists; accepted answers and bounty *wins* are not subject to the 200/day cap as documented in the faq...

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I think I wasn't clear then.  I'm not talking about giving someone more points.  I'm talking about letting them give the points the would have if they weren't capped in bounties on other peoples questions.

Comment: @JohnGB you said "it still gives an incentive to be helpful beyond 200 points / day" that incentive *already exists* -- being extra helpful gets accepts and bounty awards.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Very likely on SO, but on smaller sites like UX.SE there are almost no bounties.