# Making over-the-cap reputation useful

Tags: feature-request, daily-reputation-limit

Assuming that continuing to earn votes after hitting the daily reputation cap is considered a "Good Thing" (i.e. a behavior that the site would like to promote), I think it would be nice to think of something useful that could be done with all this over-the-cap reputation.

One example could be offering badges for earning `N` over-the-cap points for `K` days (say, the usual 1-50-150). `N` should be picked high enough as to avoid giving these badges automatically to everyone who hits the daily cap; I'm thinking "200 over" should be a reasonable pick, but perhaps it should be even higher than that.

Another example could be offering over-the-cap reputation to set bounties at some draconian exchange rate (say, 20 over-the-cap points for each bounty point you offer on someone else's question, or 40 over-the-cap points for each bounty point that you offer on your own question). So if you have 2000 over-the-cap point, you could offer a 100-point bounty on someone else's question, or a 50-point bounty on your own question.

What do you think?

Comment: Personally I think they should all be donated to Jon Skeet.

Comment: Don't we already have badges for this? http://stackoverflow.com/badges/145/epic

Comment: @Oded Looking at Jon's reputation, it's hard to escape thinking that that is already happening :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, these are for hitting the cap. I'm thinking exceeding it by 200+ points.

Comment: The repcap is one of those things that makes you bang your head against the wall each and every time you nail a 100+ answer in a single day. It takes a while to get used to it...

Comment: @Mysticial [I'm sure you know what you're talking about :)))))](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/335858)

Comment: Well... from the team's (or at least Jeff's) perspective, @RobertHarvey has some ground to stand on. Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary [were implemented as the official "do _something_ for going over the cap" solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/badge-for-upvotes-after-rep-cap-is-reached).

Comment: @PopularDemand Yeah, since the badges that I proposed would automatically imply Epic and Legendary, they would overshadow the already hard-to-get Epic and Legendary; that is not a good thing - at least in theory, different badges should be for different things. Thanks!

Comment: I proposed [something similar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140985/badges-for-significantly-exceeding-the-daily-reputation-cap-excluding-bounties) a while ago but did not meet much traction either...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You start by saying

> Assuming that continuing to earn votes after hitting the daily reputation cap is considered a "Good Thing" (i.e. a behavior that the site would like to promote)

Well... that assumption is incorrect. The reason the system has a cap is to encourage users to have some balance and to spend their time in other ways, whether on the network (e.g. answering questions on another site, editing posts, reviewing posts) or not (e.g. spending time with family, getting back to work, going outside).

Source: [Jon Skeet himself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again) (see section two, *Aims of the rep cap*)

Regarding the bounty suggestion specifically, that's been [discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107942/spare-rep-for-use-on-bounties-for-points-over-the-cap). Actually, [twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69727/can-you-use-unearned-reputation-above-rep-cap-for-bounties).

Comment: Thanks for a very simple and straightforward answer. Also thanks for pointing out the two questions on bounty suggestion - I saw only the second one when posting my question. I don't think the over-the-cap reputation should be exchanged one-for-one when setting the bounty, because that would dilute the bounty quite a bit, as there are 300+ "featured" questions already.

Comment: Yeah, for a split second I considered voting to close as a dupe of that, but I quickly decided against.

Comment: @casperOne Huh? That's the same link I posted....