# Allow users with 130 reputation or less to get one free bounty

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounties

Essentially, when you have ~100 rep, giving a 50 rep bounty could risk losing some of the basic features like editing community wikis, etc.

I believe users with such a low rep amount should be awarded one free opportunity for a 50 rep bounty so that their questions could get more interest. Users who excessively keep gaining and then losing rep can only utilize the free bounty a limited number of times.

This potentially incentivizes newcomers whose questions gain limited viewership to not stop being engaged with the SE site they're in, since the free bounty acts as a sort of reward. Additionally, the system should be limited to prevent abuse, for example, a limit on how many users can use the free bounty feature at once, avoiding sockpuppets, etc.

Comment: Bounties are overrated!

Comment: Too easy to abuse to give free rep to allies/sockpuppets.

Comment: Too much bounty will kill the impact of the bounty imo

Comment: related but answers apply: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106765/free-bounties-good-or-bad-idea?rq=1

Answer (score 11):

This is a little like saying "We need to give poor people money to spend to help the economy" - rather than dealing with why poor people are poor, and why the economy sucks.

You're essentially suggesting free reputation for low reputation users, who might not actually know what's the most effective way to use a bounty. In many cases, they *shouldn't* be using a bounty but figure its a quick/sure way to get an answer.

This might *also* mean that questions that should be closed are kept open until a mod refunds the free bounty, cause its off topic and the new user figures he can use his free bounty.

I've often offered bounties for *low* rep users on Super User for questions that interest me, or answers I feel went above and beyond. Good content ought to take care of itself.

I actually think setting a higher reputation cap for bounties makes more sense than free bounties for low rep users.

Comment: Part of the problem is that often posting a bounty is the only way to get an answer, because of all the bounty-whoring users just looking for a rep boost. I've consistently found that difficult questions only get answered when a bounty is posted.

Comment: Maybe it would help if users with plenty of rep were encouraged to post bounties on questions they thought were worthy.

Comment: @ゼーロ no, it's not. Posting a good question is *the* way to get a good answer. AFAIK I've never answered a question with an active bounty and I've never needed one to get one of my questions answered.

Comment: "Part of the problem is that often posting a bounty is the only way to get an answer, because of all the bounty-whoring users just looking for a rep boost." - I have answered hundreds of questions, only 1% of those, were awarded a bounty.

Comment: My motivation for awarding bounties on questions that belong to other people is primarily "Dang, that's interesting" . Good Hard questions get bounties. Probably helps that I have a bunch of reputation off my old sock due to a HNQ...

Answer (score 9):

That's kind of the point of bounties.  You pay reputation up front to have the privilege of your question being more prominent on the site for a while.  It doesn't matter how much rep you *start* with when you make the bounty; you just pay for it up front.

I realize that paying a 50-rep bounty when you first earn it loses you a lot of privileges, but if your question's decent enough and you participate in a high enough capacity on that site, you'll make it back in no time.