# Change the bounty description options so I don't sound like a tool

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, wording

I just offered a bounty on [one of my questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12208/how-can-i-get-the-stock-browser-to-exit) and selected "Draw attention to question" as the reason since it is the only one that applies; the question had low views and no answers (or votes).  However, the description that is shown makes me sound like a pompous idiot.

> This question has an open bounty worth +250 reputation from Matthew Read♦ ending in 7 days.
>
> This is a very interesting question that has not received enough attention

It's honestly not that interesting and, regardless, I don't really want to make that claim on my own question.  **Can we make the wording more neutral here?**  Ideally, just the simple "This question has not received enough attention."

Other options:  Something like "This question needs more or improved answers" or even "This question interests me and has not received enough attention."

Alternatively, let the optional custom reason *override* the default reason, rather than being appended beneath it.  That way I could have specified that I just wanted a solution without looking like I'm infatuated with myself.

<sub>For future reference: If you want a truckload of upvotes and to have your problem addressed quickly, call yourself a tool.  It works!</sub>

Comment: Gyah. Since when do bounties have reasons attached?

Comment: Hey hey now, nobody called you pompous. But regardless of the content - 250 points! 250 -  that's the interesting part, That's what gets 'em excited :)

Comment: I'm tempted to retag this as `[bug]` on the grounds that it's a false positive by the SE engine's this-user-is-a-pompous-tool algorithm.

Comment: By selecting that option, though, it seems you pre-agreed already, yes? The wording is vague, though. To me, "Draw attention to question" evokes fireworks or blinking HTML.

Comment: @Popular See [How should bounties be categorized?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103956/how-should-bounties-be-categorized) which got "Status completed" only 13 ours ago. It's not [listed yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) though.

Comment: @NGLN Thanks for the link! And waffles/M. Tibbit's answer even says to post a question if the list needs to be amended. Perfect.

Comment: +1 Too late, though, you already sound like a tool. :D

Comment: If the toolbox fits...

Comment: This is my fastest "Nice Question" ever.  Calling yourself names really works!

Comment: *"This is an obscure, boring question that got no attention when it was originally posted, so I'm throwing a bone in the hopes of attracting a decent answer."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for understanding my plight.

Comment: @NGLN: [Updated.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/59446/289)

Comment: Interesting - I thought "tool" was Australian English!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just updated the text to:

> This question has not received enough attention

Apologies for making you feel tool-like.

Comment: to be deployed today