# What should I do if I want more clarifications about an answer posted on an old question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, old-questions

If I want to be clarified about an answer given (and accepted as well) but the question is pretty old (ex: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329199/in-which-class-would-you-put-these-methods/1329218#1329218) in 2009), would commenting on the answer work?

Or is it OK to ask a new question giving the link to that answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> would commenting on the answer work?

Commenting the answer should send a notification to the person who posted that answer, thereby allowing the person to reply to you.

However, if you haven't received a reply, then you could ask a new question pointing to the old question and clearly mentioning what is not clear.

Comment: Maybe he means "clarification of" instead of "to clarify an"? So his question would be basically "Can someone clarify this very old answer?"

Comment: @agf yeah, hence the last line :)

Comment: yes I meant get the answer clarified .(simply : ask for more details about the answer) but I'm not going to clarify the answer itself.

Comment: @D-Shan updated question & answer

Comment: +1 for "clearly mentioning what is not clear". A simple "can someone explain in more detail" is **not** very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add a bounty to the question and [add a custom message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60338/add-a-comment-to-a-bounty) which details what you're looking for...

Comment: Does this notify the post owners as Sathya's comment method does?

Comment: @KevinVermeer: Eh, dunno if they get something in their inbox.  But if OP doesn't answer, someone will.