# Show bounty custom comments in question revision history

Tags: feature-request, bounties, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add bounty remarks to a question's revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history)

Currently, [bounty remarks are included in the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history).  However, [custom messages on the bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60338/add-a-comment-to-a-bounty) are *not*.

These comments should be shown in the revision history of the post.  It would be particularly useful when people use the custom bounty message for messages that are inappropriate, such as:

- Offering fiscal incentive to answer the question
- Spam
- Abusive/hateful speech

A current good example is the question " [error: Could not load the file or assembly 'ExcelAddIn1.XmlSerializers' or one of it's dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327396/error-could-not-load-the-file-or-assembly-exceladdin1-xmlserializers-or-one-o) ", which has the custom message of:

> I'm having the same problem and want to see if anyone has found any
>   solution to this.

However, the revision history shows the following:

[image]

Comment: "Offering fiscal incentive to answer the question" - Have people really done that? =)

Comment: @jadarnel27: Unfortunately, yes.