# Is there any way to see the custom messages/remarks of resolved/expired bounties?

Tags: support, bounties, expired-bounty, bounty-remarks

I put a bounty on [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/53297) which already have had [7 bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/2645/revisions?page=1) on it, and I'm interested in seeing their custom messages.

This was [suggested a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history) and I cannot seem to find the feature implemented anywhere in any form, so my question is:

Is there currently any way to see the custom messages of resolved and/or expired bounties?

> **Related:**
>
> - [Show bounty custom comments in question revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115860/show-bounty-custom-comments-in-question-revision-history)
> - [Add bounty remarks to a question's revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history)

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your question, but apart from that this is a dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history - could you clarify the last part if that makes it different?

Comment: @Mat The question is merely if it is possible *now*, since that question is a year old, but judging from your comment the answer is "No, this is still not possible".

Comment: Your formatting of "related" for a moment made me think it was already closed. Still voting to close, like @Mat suggested: as long as that other feature request has not been tagged as completed, nothing has changed. No need to have multiple questions about that, I feel.

Comment: Copy of my edit summary, because nobody ever looks at those: "moving custom 'related box' to bottom, because it looks like the auto-generated dupe box and to improve question previews"

Comment: @PopularDemand I didn't think of question previews, but you're right. Thanks.